# C# property assign bug

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm working on a WPF-MVVM project and I implement asynchronous infinite loops in some background threads. What I have done in the ViewModel is

```
 public TestVM()
 {
    LineIO_Task();
    //some other work
 }
```

and LineIO_Task is defined as

```
 public void LineIO_Task()
    {
        foreach (Line l in Lines) 
        {
            Task GetP = new Task(() => { EnPost(l); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            GetP.Start();
            //EnPost(Lines[i]);
        }
    }
```

Lines is an ObservableCollection that is initialized in TestVm.There are 7 items in Lines. And EnPost is defined as

```
public async void EnPost(Line l)
   {
        try
        {
            int last = 0;               
            while (true)
            {
                int pno = l.Com.ReadPostNo();//read a serial port
                if (pno != last && pno != -1 && pno != 0)
                {                                                          
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        Post p = AssignedPost.First(x => x.Num == pno);
                        if (p == null)
                        {
                            LocalDb.InsertPost(l.Num, new Post(pno));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (p.ToLine != l.Num)
                            {
                                //update UI
                                Lines.First(n => n.Num == p.ToLine).Posts.First(y => y.Num == p.Num).IsValid = true;
                                Lines.First(n => n.Num == p.ToLine).OnPropertyChanged("RealPostCount");                                  
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    last = pno;
                }
                await Task.Delay(150);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                //
        }
    }
```

AssignedPost is an ObservableCollection of Post. Post has int properties ToLine and Num.
And I have a function called Assign, which add items into AssignedPost.

```
private int Assign(Post p)
{
    int ln;
    //evaluate ln by some algorithm
    p.ToLine = ln;
    AssignedPost.Add(p);
      //some other work
    return ln;
}
```

The problem is that the item has been added into AssignedPost, i.e., `Post p = AssignedPost.First(x => x.Num == pno);` p is not null. But p.ToLine, which is supposed to be assigned before the insertion, is always 0. So the bug makes the UI update raises an error. I can't see why. Does it have something to do with multithreading?

Comment: As a note, if you read from a serial port in an async method, you shouldn't be using Task.Delay. Instead, do something like `ReadAsync` or `ReadLineAsync` on a StreamReader over the SerialPort's BaseStream. The EnPost method should also be `public async Task` instead of `async void` and be awaited like `await EnPost(l)`. Finally, instead of starting Tasks in the view model's constructor, create an async Initialize method and await the Tasks.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your advice, but could you make it more specific about the last point? I'm new to C#.

Comment: See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916649/1136211

Comment: If you need to await multiple parallel Tasks, use `Task.WhenAll`, e.g. `await Task.WhenAll(Lines.Select(l => EnPost(l)));`

Comment: What error? And where are you adding items to AssignedPost?

Comment: @mm8 6th line in Assign

Comment: I don't follow. Where do you call Assign? And what is your exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot touch the UI thread from any other thread or you run into problems.

When you want to update something for the UI you need to do:

```
View.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(a.Invoke, p);
```

Which will marshall the call to the UI thread to avoid this.

If your using something like an ObservableCollection you can use collection synchronization to call it from another thread and the calls to INotifyPropertyChanged will be marshalled to the UI thread for you.

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Entries);
```

Just make sure to turn it off when your done to avoid a memory leak like so:

```
BindingOperations.DisableCollectionSynchronization(Entries);
```